# layer.SetAttributeFilter() does not return correct number of features

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I have been using GDAL/OGR's layer.SetAttributeFilter() in a Python code to select a subset of features in a layer and save to an output shapefile. However, I am not getting the result I expect and cannot figure out why.

Here I outline my process with an example and show why the result is unexpected:

```
# First, gather a list of features that meet a specific criteria by their FID
keepFIDs = []
# iterate through features in a layer (polygon .shp):
for feature in layer:
    # if feature meets criteria:
        keepFIDs.append(feature.GetFID())

# Then, with keepFIDs, get the SQL query string:
query = "FID IN {}".format(tuple(keepFIDs))
print len(keepFIDs) # = 3991

print layer.GetFeatureCount() # = 7347 total features before applying filter

# Lastly, apply filter to layer and save to output shp
layer.SetAttributeFilter(query)
print layer.GetFeatureCount() # = 551. Why so few?! Should be 3991
print len(query.split(',')) # = 3991, for extra measure to confirm the SQL query had the correct number

# Save layer to shapefile
```

SetAttributeFilter() should be returning 3991 features, right? I mean, we know that the FIDs in the query exist in the layer I'm filtering because I just got them when iterating through features in the layer. I know from my print statements that the number of FIDs in the "FID IN " is 3991, not 551.

So what could possibly be going on?

EDIT. Here is another example to show bizarre behavior. This is a different shapefile --> layer shown here, with a lot more features:

```
# With keepFIDs, get the SQL query string:
#query = "FID IN {}".format(tuple(keepFIDs)) - not doing this here. see note below*
print len(keepFIDs) # = 7492
# *note that in this case, query is "FID IN (firstGroupOfFIDs) OR FID IN (secondGroupOfFids)"
# because of parsing issues with more than ~5000 features 
# [http://www.samuelbosch.com/2016/08/workaround-for-sql-expression-parsing.html] 
# but the output should be selecting 7492 in total:

print len(query.split('OR')[0].split(',')) # --> 4800
print len(query.split('OR')[1].split(',')) # --> 2692


print layer.GetFeatureCount() # = 89550 total features before applying filter

# Now apply filter to layer
layer.SetAttributeFilter(query)
print layer.GetFeatureCount() # = 9382. Why so many?! Should be 7492
```

Comment: Could you try to filter more in your criteria so you only get less than 551 results instead of your initial and expected 3991 results? Want to confirm if the filter string quite long could make things fail (and return 551 results instead)

Comment: Did you also count your FID uniqueness: use `print("keepFIDs unique", len(list(set(tuple(keepFIDs)))))` and `print('keepFIDs length', len(keepFIDs))` and compare. If different, it's where your issue lies.

Comment: @Thomas I did "import numpy; len(numpy.unique(keepFIDs))" and it was the same as len(keepFIDs).  Also, I just updated the question with another example to show more weirdness associated with this process. I don't know if it is what you were asking me to do but I think it answers your question that the filter string  length is likely not a factor. The second example shows the result with more features than expected this time.

Comment: Really weird. Would use another approach than using FID. Would copy the layer, add a column `filtering` to it. And set in the column, a `value1` depending of condition in your loop, then use `layer.SetAttributeFilter("filtering = 'value1'")`

Comment: @ThomasG77 thanks for the tip. I'll give that a go and see if that gives me a consistent result.

Comment: @ThomasG77 ran the same two tests with your workaround and now layer.GetFeatureCount() after applying the query does yield the correct number of features. Although it doesn't really solve why this weirdness was happening (maybe something to do with the FID field in general?) if you want to make this an answer i will accept it. cheers!